# Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) when awaiting IAsyncAction?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

It is recommended e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as much as possible on awaited tasks.

Does this recommendation also extend to methods that return `IAsyncAction`, for example [`StreamSocket.ConnectAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh701509.aspx)?

That is, instead of simply writing this in my class library:

```
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port);
```

I should rather write this?

```
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's a best practice to have any method that does not need its context, use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. The configuring is for the `await` (not the `Task` or `IAsyncAction`), and there is an `await` there that should be configured.